# DOM change background image with parameters not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<script>

    function imageChange(img)
    {

        //document.getElementsByClassName('bgdodge')[0].style.backgroundImage= "url('pictures/gtr.jpg')";
        document.getElementsByClassName('bgdodge')[0].style.backgroundImage= "url(img)";
    }
</script>


<body>

<div class= "bgdodge">
    <div id="clockbox"></div>
    <div class="pcenter">
        <p onmouseover= "imageChange('pictures/gtr.jpg')" onmouseout= "imageChange('pictures/hellcat.jpeg')"> Dodge Charger SRT Hellcat</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works when  I do it like in the comment in the imageChange function without the parameters. But when passing the pictures onmouseover and mouseout to imageChange and using the "img" variable, it doesnt work. Idk why

Answer (score 2):

You're just using the string "img" but you really mean to be using the variable:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bgdodge')[0].style.backgroundImage= "url("+img+")";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this example

```js
function screen(){
alert('ddd')
const render = node =>
  domtoimage.toPng(node)
  .then(dataUrl => {
  console.log(performance.now()-pf)
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    $('body').append(img);
  })
  .catch(error =>
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error)
  );

const foo = document.getElementById('foo');

var pf=performance.now();
render(foo);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/bfc00a6c5bba731027820199acd7b0a6e92149d8/dist/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <div >foo</div>
<button onclick="screen()">shot</button>
</div>
```